# How do I programmatically make a UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

How to make a UILabel programmatically?

Comment: you need to first search the Question , if wouldn't find answer then ask for help.This very simple question then really you need to work hard.

Comment: you should also mark your answers as 'answered' to "close" this question. i recommend you to google for such easy things or you can ask in the iPhone iPad developer chat:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad

Comment: @Rohit: your previous question was almost same and it has the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086376/how-to-program-uilabel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake
(50, 100, 200, 100)];  
myLabel.text = @"Lorem...";  //add text to your label
[self.view addSubview:myLabel]; //add label to your view
```

that should help you out.

Why are asking this easy question? if you search for it, click the first result on google and you have your answer.